# String formatting with placeholders

Tags: python, string-formatting, ternary-operator

Is it possible to use placeholders in string formatting? An example will probably show what I mean:

```
"some {plural?'people':'person'}".format(plural=True)
```

Should be "some people". Basically, can I switch between two options in a format string, rather than directly provide all the values e.g.:

```
"some {plural}".format(plural="people")
```

This may sound a bit useless, but the use case is many strings with several words that *could* be plural, and this would drastically simplify the code.

Comment: No, that functionality is not part of Python format strings.

Comment: why don't define a function where you check if you need plural or singular. have a list with all singular and plural forms.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel's idea would be the most portable. Another that I've personally used is a combination of relatively simple in-line conditional expressions and a standalone function name `pluralize()`: For example: `"%d*day%s" % (self.dperiod, pluralize(self.dperiod))`. The definition of `pluralize()` being `def pluralize(count, ending='s', ones=(-1, 1)):`, `return ending if count not in ones else ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible **after Python 3.6** using [f-strings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
plural = True
print(f"some { 'people' if plural else 'person' }")
```

Note that `a if condition else b` is a Python expression, not a f-string feature, so you can use `'thing' if plural else 'things'` anywhere where you would need that, not just in f-strings.

Or, if you have a function to pluralize (could just be a `dict` lookup), you can do:

```
print(f"{ pluralize('person', plural) }")
```

Comment: f-strings can indeed be very useful—but I hesitate to use them because they don't work and the many previous versions of Python...so that fact likely should also be taken in consideration when deciding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary:

```
plural = False
>>> print("some {people}".format(people='people' if plural else 'person'))
some person
```

You could also create a dictionary holding tuple pairs of singular and plural words which can be accessed via a boolean.

```
irregulars = {
    'person': ['person', 'people'],
    'has': ['has', 'have'],
    'tooth': ['tooth', 'teeth'],
    'a': [' a', ''],
}

plural = True
words = [irregulars[word][plural] for word in ('person', 'has', 'a', 'tooth')]
print('some {} {}{} crooked {}'.format(*words))

plural = False
words = [irregulars[word][plural] for word in ('person', 'has', 'a', 'tooth')]
print('some {} {}{} crooked {}'.format(*words))

# Output:
# some people have crooked teeth
# some person has a crooked tooth
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be ideal for my use case, where I could have multiple words requiring a plural form in a template string.

Comment: I didn't realise you could pass a list of words to format, thanks. I've gone with the f-string answer because I could have thousands of strings - each with a couple pluralisable words, and it would be simpler to be able to store the plural and non-plural forms for each string in the string itself, rather than in a central dictionary. Also, I'd be able to see what the string would look like just by reading it, without having to reference a dictionary to find the plural forms.